# Setting margin left equal to sum of width of previous elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m working on horizontal scroll website and want to set left margin for element based on sum of width of previous elements.
But till element with **class="block-5"** its working fine and after that its taking too much value for left. Not getting what is the issue exactly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="scroll-main-wrapper" class="container main-wrapper">
      <div class="common-wrapper block-1" width="230">
        <div style="background-image: url(images/img.png);">
          <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-2" width="546">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/groom.jpg);">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/bride.jpg);">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-3" width="230">
        <img src="images/pattern.png" alt="pattern">
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-4 text-center" width="286">
        <img src="images/img-bg.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
        <p class="title">Title</p>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-5" width="1578">
        <div class="vertically-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
              <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
              <p class="chapter-title">Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-6" width="740">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-7 text-center" width="230">
        <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var left = 0;
  $('#scroll-main-wrapper .common-wrapper').each(function() {
    $(this).css('left', left);
    left += $(this).outerWidth() + 40;
  });
```

**CSS**

```
.common-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 62px;
  bottom: 0px;
  min-width: 230px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border: 1px rgba(244, 200, 113, 0.3) solid;
}
```

**RESULT**

```
    <div id="scroll-main-wrapper" class="container main-wrapper">
  <div class="common-wrapper block-1" style="left: 0px;">
    <div style="background-image: url(images/img.png);">
      <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="common-wrapper block-2" style="left: 270px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/groom.jpg);">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/bride.jpg);">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="common-wrapper block-3" style="left: 856px;">
    <img src="images/pattern.png" alt="pattern">
  </div>
  <div class="common-wrapper block-4 text-center" style="left: 1126px;">
    <img src="images/img-bg.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
    <p class="title">Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="common-wrapper block-5" style="left: 1452px;">
    <div class="vertically-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
          <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
          <p class="chapter-title">Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="common-wrapper block-6" style="left: 7096px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="common-wrapper block-7 text-center" style="left: 8040px;">
    <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: can you put these codes in a jsfiddle/plunker and share the link?

Comment: I tried creating plunker but its giving error Jquery is not defined as I'm using a plugin [jInvertScroll](http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/).

Comment: I found the solution. There was some small issue with my code.

Answer (score 0):

change to html `width` to `style="width:"`

```
<div id="scroll-main-wrapper" class="container main-wrapper">
      <div class="common-wrapper block-1" style="width:230px;">
        <div style="background-image: url(images/img.png);">
          <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-2" style="width:546px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/groom.jpg);">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/bride.jpg);">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-3" style="width:230px;">
        <img src="images/pattern.png" alt="pattern">
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-4 text-center" style="width:286px;">
        <img src="images/img-bg.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
        <p class="title">Title</p>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-5" style="width:1578px;">
        <div class="vertically-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
              <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
              <p class="chapter-title">Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-6" style="width:740px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="common-wrapper block-7 text-center" style="width:230px;">
        <img src="images/img.png" alt="bg-img" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n6aaz3o7/3/

Comment: Thanks for replying.. :)  but I'm not setting width actually in my code. Its dynamic based on the content. Here I wrote width="" just for your reference.

Comment: 1st div 232px width, 2nd div 232px + 40 = left to 272 right ?

Comment: removing width is ok, but its the same code which I'm using then what is the issue with my code that I'm not getting. Is it because of the [jInvertScroll](http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/) plugin?

Comment: Till 5th div it is fine. After that its not working properly.